# What is the kernel and range of T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the linear transformation T by T($\vec x$) = A$\vec x$. Find (1) the kernel of T and (2) the range of T

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1\\0&2&1\end{bmatrix}$

> 1) Finding the Kernel(T)

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1\\0&2&1\end{bmatrix}$ => RREF $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&.5\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-2x_3\\-.5x_3\\t\end{bmatrix}$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}-2t\\-.5t\\t\end{bmatrix}$ = 
t$\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-.5\\1\end{bmatrix}$

**My Answer - Kernel(T) = {t(-2, -.5, -1)}, t is any real number**

> 2) Finding the Range(T)

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1\\0&2&1\end{bmatrix}$ => RREF $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&.5\end{bmatrix}$

**My Answer - Basis for range(T) = {(1.0), (0,1)}**

This is what I got for the kernel and range, however the answer words it in an odd way. It says "Kernel of A is null space of A which is span{(4,1,-2)} and the Range of A is $R^2$.

Is my answer equivalent with the book's answer? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: The span of $(4, 1, -2)$ is the same as the span of $(-2, -1/2, 1)$, which is what you found (minus your typo in writing down the final answer from the line before it). You found a basis for the range which has dimension $2$, so the range is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I would be a bit pedantic and say that although saying that the basis for the range of $T$ being $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ (*or their transposes if you prefer*) will clearly *imply* that the range of $T$ is all of $\Bbb R^2$, the question did ask you for what the range of $T$ *was*, it did not ask you what a *basis* for the range of $T$ was.  It is like answering "The 45th president of the united states" rather than "Donald Trump" when asked the question of "Who is the current president of the united states?"

Comment: Just to check your understanding: are you saying that this is the basis for the range of $T$ because those are the first two columns of the RREF or because the RREF tells you that the rank of the matrix is 2 and so the range is all of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: I am saying this is the basis for the range of T because those are the first two columns of the RREF that have a 1 as the first non-zero number.

Comment: That’s wrong, though in this case it happens to give you a correct answer. The pivot columns of the RREF generally do not themselves form a basis for the range (column space), but indicate which of the columns of the _original_ matrix do. E.g., the RREF of $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$ is $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}$, but $(1,0)^T$ is obviously not a basis for its column space.

Comment: oh gotcha. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers match those of the book; they're just written differently. Note that if you set $t = -2$, you will see that the set of vectors spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ -0.5 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is the same as that spanned by $\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}$. Similarly, $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \right\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.